# Random password generator with prompts

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an assignment that requires prompts asking for password length and character type and I have two issues:

- a) The prompts aren't showing up
- b) I cant seem to put the password in my display box. Here is my code:

```js
var length = Number(prompt("How many characters will your password be? Enter a number between 8 and 128"));

//ask for character type
var charType = prompt("Enter a character type: special, numeric, uppercase, lowercase.");

//generate password
function generatePassword() {
  //evaluate character type
  var charSet = "";
  var charTypeLower = charType.toLowerCase();
  if (charTypeLower === "lowercase") {
    charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  } else if (charTypeLower === "uppercase") {
    charSet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  } else if (charTypeLower === "numeric") {
    charSet = "0123456789";
  } else if (charTypeLower === "special") {
    charSet = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~";
  }
  //return value
  var retVal = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //picks a character within charSet at index of random number
    retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length));
  }
  return retVal;
}
alert(generatePassword());
}
//make password appear in display box
document.getElementById("display").value = password;

//function to copy password to clipboard
function copyPassword() {

  document.getElementById("display").select();

  document.execCommand("Copy");

  alert("Password copied to clipboard!");
```

Comment: Just sintax problem you need to remove the `}` after `alert(generatePassword());` and add one after `alert("Password copied to clipboard!");`

Answer (score 0):

You had a `}` after your `alert`, which was throwing an error and preventing the prompts from showing. I applied some other fixes as well:

```js
var length = Number(prompt("Enter a password length between 8 and 128")),
  charType = prompt("Enter a character type: special, numeric, uppercase, lowercase."),
  password = generatePassword();
document.getElementById("display").value = password;
document.getElementById('copy-btn').addEventListener('click', copyPassword);

function generatePassword() {
  var charSets = {
    lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    numeric: '0123456789',
    special: ' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
  };
  var charSet = charSets[charType.toLowerCase()] || charSets.lowercase;
  var retVal = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length));
  }
  return retVal;
}

function copyPassword() {
  document.getElementById("display").select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Password copied to clipboard!");
}
```

```html
<input id="display"> <button id="copy-btn">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Wow thank you! It's looking a lot better but I notice it asks me each of those prompts twice before giving me a password. What can I do about this?

Comment: @AiyaSiddig The answer I gave you only gives you the prompts once. I don't know what your code looks like, so it's hard to tell... Maybe provide a full version of your code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the issue